# Is $\{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cos{nx}\}, n=1,2,3...$ a complete basis in $L^2([0, \pi])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

The above is an exercise in *Beginning Functional Analysis* by Saxe. I approach the problem by extending an arbitrary function symmetrically to $-\pi$ and arguing via the convergence of the classical Fourier Series. However, I can’t avoid the need for an initial term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. I have found this initial term included in one or two places online, but this evidence is tentative.

I am aware of an answered question with regard to the analogous sine series, but to infer that it directly applies is to assume the answer is likewise analogous.

Comment: The function $1$ cannot be expanded in an $L^2[0,\pi]$ series of functions $\{ \cos(nx) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ because $\int_0^{\pi} 1\cdot \cos(nx)dx = 0$.

Comment: Fair point. I’m still confused as to what the first term is, in light of observations further below. (I’d upvote your comment, but my preferences are not yet seen as valid.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a self-adjoint eigenfunction problem:
$$
             -y''=\lambda y,\;\;\; y'(0)=y'(\pi)=0.
$$
The eigenfunctions of this problem form an orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$. The un-normalized eigenfunctions are
$$
               1,\cos(x),\cos(2x),\cos(3x),\cdots.
$$
So the normalized eigenfunctions form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$:
$$
                 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cos(nx),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdot.
$$
The problem $-y''=\lambda y$ with $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$ gives the usual $\sin$ basis
$$
                      \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,4,\cdots.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $\{e_n\}$ is a complete basis and $\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$ then $x=0$.

Comment: I’ve since found corroboration in a different textbook that the addition of the initial term I’ve suggested makes this into a complete orthonormal sequence. However, $\langle\cos{2x},\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cos{nx}\rangle=\langle\cos{2x},\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\rangle=0$, yet $\cos{2x}$ is not zero a.e. I’m therefore wondering if the theorem you quote applies beyond the classical system on $L^{2}([-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: The proof of the theorem in question has nothing to suggest validity only on the classical system, so this is pretty confusing.

Comment: Your computation is not correct: $\langle\cos(2x),\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cos(2x)\rangle\neq 0$. The theorem that I quoted is very general as it holds for any complete basis in a Hilbert space.

Comment: Damn. Agreed! Thanks for your help. Your hint was probably better aimed at Saxe than at me, since the orthonormal sequence should have been correctly stated in the printed question I was attempting to answer. By the way, I thank Rynne & Youngston for stating the basis correctly (and, incidentally, maintaining online errata for their own textbook).